# How did Madara Uchiha survive such a long time?

Tags: naruto

In the last chapters of the manga,

> When Tobi finally admits he is Obito and starts to remember what happened after the rock hit him, he meets Madara. How is this possible? Hundreds of years must have passed; how was he able to survive so long?

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/98/27)

Comment: but is an answer not a question... that's why i didn't see it.

Comment: I have the impression only some 100 years have passed. So, although unusual, it is possible for people to live that long. Anyhow, Madara's answer explains it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Madara, when he was close to death, awakened the Rinnegan.

The Rinnegan allowed him to break the seal placed by the Sage of the Six Paths, and summon the Juubi's shell (The Gedo Mazo) from the moon.

Using it as a catalyst, Madara used Hashirama's cells in order to extend his own lifespan.

Once disconnected from the Mazo, Madara died instantly.

Comment: and why did he disconnected from the Mazo?

Comment: @Washu: His plan with Obito was that Madara will be revived using the Rinnegan he implanted into Nagato. For that, Madara would have to be dead.

Answer (score -1):

Madara Uchiha didn't survive. The one who everybody thinks is Madara is acually Obito Uchiha because Obito said that he was going to take on Madara's legacy. This means the day of the nine tails attack Minato was actually fighting his own student. "Madara" (Obito Uchiha) is the one who set the nine tails lose and he says his name is Tobi which is just Obito switched all around with one "o" taken off.

Comment: I've fixed your grammar for this post, but I'm not sure this answers the question that was being asked. It would help if you could add some form of citations or support for your answer.